# mysql shutting too frequently

Tags: mysql, database

MySql shutting frequently:
I am getting this error:

```
2019-12-30T15:29:35.139597Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 23 in a file operation.
2019-12-30T15:29:35.139597Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2019-12-30T15:29:35.139597Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: File .\pink_square_wov\sales_entry_header.ibd: 'Windows aio' returned OS error 123. Cannot continue operation
2019-12-30T15:29:35.139597Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
2019-12-30T15:29:39.341887Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2019-12-30T15:31:24.046589Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: 13 threads created by InnoDB had not exited at shutdown!
```

How can I fix that

I am using:

**MySql 5.7.17**

**Windows 10**

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706568/innodb-operating-system-error-number-23-in-a-file-operation - too many open files?

Comment: @Caramiriel no, I just formatted the computer, but the issue still remains :(

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645700/error-code-23-out-of-resources-when-opening-file/31645955?

Comment: @Caramiriel Not helping :(